# Exporting .SWF to CMS/Filestore

Tags: business-objects, xcelsius

I have a couple of .SWF files that I am trying to get onto our BOBJ server and am having no luck. I am using XCelsius 2008 SP3.3 and trying to put it on an XI R3 server.

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting an error message?
You can publish SWF via the Xcelsius designer tool (File > Export > BusinessObjects Platform) or by using the BusinessObjects Publishing Wizard.

Comment: I am not able to open a SWF File. I get an error about corruption when i try. I can export a XLF no problem but, again the SWF fails to even open. Should I be able to open the SWF?

Comment: You cannot open the SWF in Xcelsius designer, as it is the compiled output of the XLF. but when you have the XLF open in Xcelsius you can export to SWF or export to BusinessObjects Platform.